# how to omit vowels in a word or sentence in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Somehow I can't run my program. I'm hoping you could guys help me. I'm a beginner in programming.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Word: ");
        String input = scan.next();

        String[] strArray = new String[input.length()];
        String ch = "", out = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            strArray[i] = input.charAt(i) + "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            ch = strArray[i];
            out = (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) ? "" // "?" = if
                    : (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) ? "" // ":" = else
                          : (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("I")) ? ""
                                 : (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) ? ""
                                      : (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) ? "" : ch;
            System.out.print(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Working fine...What's your problem ?

Comment: actually that's my problem is i can't make it run. but somehow I'm sure i do it right.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would say something about the problem. Is it a compile time error, a runtime error or your code is executing fine but having unexpected output?

Comment: whenever i compile it this is what it shows me:
 Main.java:5: error: class Test is public, should be declared in a file named Test.java
public class Test {
       ^
1 error

Comment: [Can't find any problem.](http://ideone.com/AN7ryZ). I'm voting to close this question as unclear what are you asking.

Comment: You said "I'm a beginner to the programming". Are you naming your file Test.java ??

Comment: *"class Test is public, should be declared in a file named Test.java "* What is unclear about that? Does the file name matches  the class name?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `replaceAll()` method of String. `replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUuYy]", "")` will remove each of those letters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner, I'm gonna give some extra explanation and advice that hope will help you.

1) As for your main problem, the error states that the name of the file is wrong. in Java, the name of the file that contains the code should be the same as of the public class you declare (a must, not like c++) .. so you should name your file as Test.java and your class declaration is: public class Test { ... }

2) your code works fine as logic, but it's not the best way to do this. As answered by jsheeran, using something called regular expression is much better than implementing a for loop. see  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html 
for an intro about regular expressions. and if you don't understand it, it's OK. just take the general idea and use the replaceAll function.

3) A note for you that's not related to the problem you mentioned, is that whenever you deal with I/O classes in Java (like Scanner), you should close the Streaming source, otherwise, this could cause memory leak. so at the end of your code, add:

```
scan.close();
```

4) and finally, don't import classes that you don't need. it won't make any problem, but why import them. so, remove:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
```

By the way, java.lang is automatically imported, so you'll never need to import it.

5) And a last tip, if you are a beginner and you have time to learn, don't just use tutorials from the internet, but rather read a good easy-to-read java book. I would recommend "Head first java, 2nd edition". Also, video tutorials might be better for you than reading tutorials.

Comment: @NOOBProgrammer: please accept this answer. That is good practice on SO. Although tge other answer has more votes (and contains a valid good suggestion), this one is more applicable to your actual problem